# Is toString called for primitive types also?

Tags: java, tostring

I know that `toString` is called in `Java` whenever we print an object, and that is by default defined in `Object` class which is superclass of all classes.

But, my teachers says that `toString` is also called when we print some `primitive type` (`int, char` etc).

Is that true ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, but not in the sense that you would expect it to be.

```
System.out.println(someInt)
```

is just a wrapper for `print` that also adds a line.

```
System.out.print(someInt)
```

[calls](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/PrintWriter.java.html#531)

```
String.valueOf(someInt)
```

which in turn [calls](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html#3001)

```
Integer.toString(someInt)
```

which is [a static method](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html#321) in the Integer class that [returns a `String` object representing the specified integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29). This method is *not* the same as `Integer#toString()`, an instance method that transforms its Integer object into a string representing its int value.

`someInt.toString()` won't work as `someInt` does not extend `Object` due to its not being an object.

Comment: `will call (indirectly, possibly)` you could elaborate on this part a bit. Why the possibly?

Comment: thanks to all of you...really appreciate all of you, as this was my first question

Comment: @user2753864 No problem. Feel free to ask and answer at your leisure.

Comment: Good answer, I'd like to re-iterate, however: `Integer.toString(int)` is a *static* method with a single parameter. It's *very different* from `Integer.toString()`, which is a no-argument, non-static method (and which is what you'd usually mean if you say just "Integer.toString").

Answer (score 24):

Lets see how `System.out.print(int)` works. According to `System` API `System.out` is a `PrintStream`:

```
public static final PrintStream out
```

In `PrintStream` src we can see how it prints ints:

```
public void print(int i) {
    write(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

And this is `String.valueOf(int)` from `String` src:

```
public static String valueOf(int i) {
    return Integer.toString(i);
}
```

Comment: Very good answer, helps understanding and teaches how to find the solution on ones own the next time.

Comment: `PrintStream` is not `final`, and neither is `PrintStream.print(int)`. It is possible to change `out` (with the `setOut` method) to a new derived class that changes the behavior of this method. In practice, this should rarely (virtually never) matter. Especially not for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider following code

```
System.out.println(5);
```

Following thing will happen

```
public void println(int x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

function from `PrintStream` class will be called which internally will call `print(x)` function as follows-

```
public void print(int i) {
    write(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

and now if you see valueOf() function in String class

```
public static String valueOf(int i) {
    return Integer.toString(i);
}
```

and

`Integer.toString(i)` is what your teacher meant by calling toString() method.

Comment: `Integer.toString(i)` is _not_ autoboxing at all. There is no autoboxing going on here. _If_ there was no `println(int)` method, and only `println(Object)`, then it would be called by `println(5)` and that would be autoboxing.

Comment: Agreed! Updated the answer. There is not autoboxing involved.

Comment: Nice and complete explanation. Maybe adding the exact Java version could make it more appropriate, though these are bits that are not changing very often.

Answer (score 0):

The primitives are **autoboxed** to their respective object type. So `toString()` will call.

Comment: This is incorrect. `println` is overloaded to work with primitives as well.

Comment: I'd disagree. See Evgeniy Dorofeev's answer for an explanation why.

Comment: Not for `println()`. See Evgeniy Dorofeev answer.